# C# -Make a zip file from List of file paths

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a number of folders and I have number of file in each folders.
I am taking some of the file paths from different folders and I need to zip those files into a single zip file.

if I have the file in a single folder, I can do zip using

```
string startPath = @"c:\example\start";//folder to add
string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";//URL for your ZIP file
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath, CompressionLevel.Fastest, true);
string extractPath = @"c:\example\extract";//path to extract
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
using (ZipArchive newFile = ZipFile.Open(zipName, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
{
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(myPath))
    {
        newFile.CreateEntryFromFile(file);
    }
}
```

Suppose I don't know about the folders, I only have a list of file paths, I need to foreach through each file path and add into the zip. What should I do for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enumerate all files in the directory include subdirectories with [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx) overloading and `SearchOption.AllDirectories` option and then use it

```
String[] allfiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("myPath", "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (string file in allfiles)
{
    newFile.CreateEntryFromFile(file);
}
```

You can use [`ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(string sourceDirectoryName, string destinationArchiveFileName)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485707(v=vs.110).aspx) or its overload to create an archive in one step too.

Also there is a way to manipulate zip archive structure more flexibly via [`Path.GetDirectoryName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Here is the example:

```
foreach(var filePath in files)
{
    var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    var entry = archive.GetEntryFromFile(filePath, $"{directory}/{fileName}");
}
```

Finally, you can use 3rd party library [DotNetZip](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) and solve yor scenario in just 3 lines of code:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.AddFiles(files);
    zip.Save("Archive.zip");
}
```

Comment: its not about sub directries, just let it be you have an array of filepaths like ["\folder1\auditnew.JPG","\folder2\audi.JPG"] from this array how will i can create a zip?

Comment: @hildasonica can't understand yor problem. [CreateEntryFromFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485720(v=vs.110).aspx) can manipulate file names in the archive with second parameter. If you need to have copy of the folder structure you can just ignore it or modify source file pathes if you want.

Comment: in the above code you are using a method called GetFiles to get all the files from a paricular folder, in my case, i will have a list of file paths, which i will fetch from the database. and using those filepath(or fieurl) i need to make the zip, i think i cant use the GetFiles() method here

Comment: @hildasonica yeap it'll work and also I edited my answer to solve your scenario with DotNetZip in a shorter manner.

Comment: @VadimMartynov using your dotnetzip example how is it then downloading the files?

Answer (score 1):

Using the DotNetZip library from newget manager, just check whether it will work or not

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    foreach(var filestring in AllFileArray)
    {
        zip.AddFile(filestring);
    }
    zip.save("MyZipFile.zip")
}
```

Comment: How can you then download those files using this?